# setDismissDelay to zero for tooltip manager

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I set a dismissdelay '0' for a button tooltip. In windows I can't see the tooltip but In linux I am able to see the tooltip. In the java  source code of javax.swing.ToolTipManager I did not find any platform dependent info.

Anyone have any idea?

```
public class TooltipInSwing extends JFrame {
    public TooltipInSwing() {
        super("TooltipInSwing");
        setSize(400, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Simple tooltip 1");
        b1.setToolTipText("simple tool tip without a dismiss delay" + ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().getInitialDelay());
        // set a new dismiss delay to a really big value, default is 4 sec.
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(0);
        getContentPane().add(b1);
        WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        addWindowListener(wndCloser);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TooltipInSwing();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this question? Maybe, there is different behaviour, but why would you ever want a dismiss delay of 0? This implies that the tooltip should never display. If this is what you want then set the tooltip text to null and the tooltip will not display. Otherwise,what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @camickr Thank you for reply.  I accidently saw this behavior then I thought that there may be some real reason behind it. I did a try my own but was not able to find it. That's why the question